# Setting up Media Queries for a header image on Wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have the WP site http://selfreliantschool.com/ using the Genesis framework with a child theme. Currently the image is totally non-responsive - doesn't scale as the screen shrinks. I added this:

```
    .header-image .site-title a {
         background-size: contain !important;
    }
```

to the

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
```

section and was able to get the width of the image to scale properly, but I wind up with white space below it (above the menu). The css for that bit outside of the media query is:

```
.header-image .site-title a {
   background-color: none;
   margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 1070px;
   min-height: 115px;
   padding: 0;
}
```

So it's keeping the 115 height no matter the width. Any suggestions on getting height to scale as well?

Answer (score 0):

Using `background-size:cover;` will give a similar effect to `contain` (scale in ratio) but always cover the visible area of the element it is the background of rather than show all the image.

Comment: Nope, using cover instead of contain has no effect - the image doesn't scale at all, just gets chopped off on the right.

Comment: Because the image is in the background the element's height cannot be decided by the image. Possibly via some Javascript and/or some clever math given a fixed starting width/height etc you could do it.

Alternatively you could adjust the height of the element based on the assumed width?

Playing with inspect element on your site, `background-size:cover!important;background-position:20% 0!important;` worked until very small sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not the css above:

Fix

```
.site-title a {
   background: url(http://selfreliantschool.com/wp- content/uploads/2015/02/Graceful-banner-SRS-three6.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
   background-size: contain !important;
   background-position: center !important;
}
```

Note: I have had to use !important as there is multiple media queries along the window resize. You could probably clean up the css a bit saving space and confusion.

Comment: Didn't work. I pulled the custom header code from functions.php that injects the style above into the html (that's how Genesis does it) and dropped yours into the css file. With that, the header is always sized down to 320 width, no matter the actual screen size, and I still have the whitespace under it (the 115 height)

Comment: it worked with chrome. Make sure the style above is not replacing `.header-image .site-title a{}` rule above , just delete the rule  `.site-title a {}` and replace with the one in the answer. As i said your css is messy and you may have other rules affecting the code above depending on where you put the code, try `!important` after the background: property (dont put no-repeat in there)